# How to re-populate form with old data if a validation error occurs?

Tags: laravel

The problem here is that the country field is not being re-populated whenever I submit the form. What I expect is for the user to submit the form and have the server validate it and redirect back with the errors and keep the data that the user input before submitting.

For some unknown reason, the country field is not getting the old input but the state field is getting the old input perfectly.

`<select  id="country" name ="country" class="form-control rounded input-lg text-center no-border"  required autofocus  <option> </option>
</select> </br>
<select name ="state" id ="state" class="form-control rounded input-lg text-center no-border" required autofocus
 <option>{{ Request::old('state') }}</option>
</select> </br>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use just [`old()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#old-input) for that:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

Another way to do that is to use [Laravel Collective form model binding](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#form-model-binding):

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.update', $user->id]]) !!}
```

In this case all form data will be re-populated automatically.

Comment: Hey Alexey,
Thanks for the reply.  I wanted to avoid using the form builder because I am using a lot of input fields in my form and I don't know if the form builder will support them.

Comment: @TonyBatista, if you're using a lot of input, I'd especially recommend you to use Laravel Collective forms. ) It makes handling forms so much easier.